# How can I allow https connection using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, afnetworking

I have AFNetworking set up but it is not accept https urls. How can I get AFNEtworking to connect via ssl.

I have the following code:

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
[self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                path: pathstr
                          parameters: params
           constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
           {
               //TODO: attach file if needed
           }];



AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //success!
    completionBlock(responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //failure :(

    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: What error is reported in your log? Also, is your server cert valid?

Answer (score 14):

```
operation.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

This code is very important. If you dont add this you will get an error.

Comment: This is perfect and more clean.

Answer (score 6):

This will obviously only work if you have a non self-signed cert OR you add:

#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ to your pch file. If you are using cocoa pods for this you will likely need to subclass AFHTTPRequestOperation and implement:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    if ([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {

        if ([self bypassSslCertValidation:protectionSpace])
            return YES;
        else
            return [super connection:connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

    }
    return [super connection:connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        if ([self bypassSslCertValidation:challenge.protectionSpace]) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            return;
        }
        else
            return [super connection:connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        return;
    }
}

- (BOOL) bypassSslCertValidation:(NSURLProtectionSpace *) protectionSpace
{
    if (ENVIRONMENT_TYPE == DEV_ENV || ENVIRONMENT_TYPE == STAGING_ENV) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Then tell AFNEtworking to use the new subclass:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[YourSubClassHTTPRequestOperation class]];
```

It's not the easiest thing to do in the world and technically ignoring self-signed isn't making it work, but if you use standard SLL certificates It's probable it will work just fine, remember to remove this code or make it only available when debugging if you plan to release.

Adding to answer because comments have char limits!

Few choices looking at the [headers](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h)

Return operation that can be manually added to the queue:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
```

Or pass in your custom subclass operation to this one:

```
- (void)enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation;
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I have found, I literally just implemented this yesterday for my local SSL development, you can even go so far as to tell it what hosts to ignore SSL for. I heard somewhere they added SSL Pinning, I'd hit google for it.

Comment: Where do I tell AfNetworking to implement the AFHTTPClient subclass? How do I change my codeabove to do so... Thanks!

Comment: It's not a subclass on AFHTTPClient its on the AFHTTPRequestOperation class, then if you were using RestKit you would just set them on the HTTClient property of the sharedManager, however not using a base kit for this you probably have an object that manages AFHTTPClient already, you would just add the [client registerHTTPOperationClass:YourSubClass] message (wording is probably off typing from vague memory not in xcode.)

Comment: this solution does not work for me.what can i be doing wrong?

Comment: Updated answer with some options, to long for comments

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
[self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                path: pathstr
                          parameters: params
           constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
           {
               //TODO: attach file if needed
           }];



AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //success!
    completionBlock(responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //failure :(

    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
}];
operation.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
[operation start];
```

Comment: This will allow you to use the https connection but will not be a secure connection. It means you need to setup securityPolicy with your *.cer certificates from your web service to have a secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

If AFNetworking is disabled subclass over superclass implementation then simply put in code like :http//foo//bar and set this to bool